# Как в хроме исправить подгрузку текста в блоке при резкой прокрутки страницы?

Tags: html, css

На сайте есть модальное окно с политикой конфендициальности.
Из за того, что в нем много текста, когда быстро прокручиваешь весь блок просто плывет.
Можно ли это исправить? Данная проблема только в хроме.

```
<div class="modal__content">

<div class="modal__close--policy">
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="policy__wrap">

    <p class="policy__header">Политика в отношении обработки персональных данных</p>

    <p class="policy__title">1. Общие положения</p> 

</div>
```

```
@function vw($value, $base: 1920){
    @return $value / $base * 100vw;
}

@function vmin($value, $base: 428){
    @return $value / $base * 100vw;
}

body{
    background: #182B2C;
}

.modal__content{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: vw(150);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 999999;

    width: vw(1172);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0px vw(21) vw(74) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    backdrop-filter: blur(vw(20));
    border-radius: vw(41);
    padding: vw(45) vw(30);

    &::before{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        inset: 0;
        border-radius: vw(41);
        padding: vw(1);
        background: linear-gradient(179.22deg, rgba(175, 253, 255, 0) 0.7%, #AFFDFF 52.82%, rgba(175, 253, 255, 0) 100.77%),
            linear-gradient(89.92deg, rgba(175, 253, 255, 0) -1.09%, #AFFDFF 51.52%, rgba(175, 253, 255, 0) 99.92%);
        -webkit-mask: 
            linear-gradient(white 0 0) content-box, 
            linear-gradient(white 0 0);
        -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
        mask-composite: exclude;
    }
}

p.policy__header{
    font-size: vw(36);
    color: white;
}

p.policy__title{
    font-size: vw(24);
    padding-top: vw(30);
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: vw(15);
    color: white;
}

p.policy__text{
    font-size: vw(18);
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
}

.policy__wrap{
    li{
        font-size: vw(18);
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: vw(30);
        padding-top: vw(15);
        line-height: 120%;
    }
}
```

Ссылка на [codepen](https://codepen.io/Kaidos/pen/XWEoxLx).

Comment: что значит "плывёт"?

Comment: у меня в хроме по вашей ссылке ничего не "плывет"